# Print multiplication table of any number in an alert box in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, alert

I want to show a table (multiplication one) after taking number (as an input) from user in an alert box. But the problem is under loop, as loop runs 10 times, alert box also is shown 10 times. I've tried using id, wrote alert code outside loop but it doesn't work correctly. So is  it possible to show the output in one alert box instead of showing it in 10 alert boxes? Also alert box don't seem to be interpret "br" correctly. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: Build up a string. new lines in alerts is \n, not br

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that placing alert in a for loop will... show one alert with one number, followed by another alert with another number, etc.

You want to first create the whole body of the alert (using the for loop) and after that alert once.

```
<script>
function table()
{
  var x=prompt("Enter a number:",2);
  var alertBody = '';
  for (var i=1; i<10; i++) {
    alertBody += x + "*" + i +"="+x*i + '\n';
  }
  alert(alertBody);
}
</script>
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/oVuwINa/1/edit

Comment: Thanks :) its working. Another member suggested the same answer and when i came back after trying to mark his answer he had deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

What about \n instead of br?

if you are doing it this way

Alert -> get input

loop and store your result

Alert -> show output

then it should be working fine